# Replace the audio stream of a video using NAudio

Tags: c#, audio, video, naudio, ms-media-foundation

I have 2 files. Both are the same length (in seconds):

1. a video file (H.264, .mov)
2. an audio file (PCM, .wav)

How do I use the NAudio .NET library in my C# application to overwrite the audio of file #1 with the audio from file #2? I want to write the final result to disk as a new video file.

I believe this is possible using the Media Foundation capabilities of NAudio 1.7, but I can't figure out how to modify the audio stream of a video file and re-save the video.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible with NAudio 1.7. NAudio has interop wrappers for a large percentage of the Media Foundation API, but the focus of the `MediaFoundationReader` and `MediaFoundationEncoder` classes is just on the audio. It should be possible with Media Foundation, so if you can find a C++ sample that does this with the MF API, you could recreate it in C# using the interop wrappers from NAudio. Alternatively you could try using a different managed Media Foundation library, such as [Media Foundation .NET](http://mfnet.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I'm glad I asked! Aside from it being difficult for me to determine what's possible with the API, thanks for your great work on NAudio.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FFMPEG to do that. Call FFMPEG from  c# and find the command to merge Video with Audio.